# jquery validate message is not showing for all input field first time

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, jquery-ui

I have used j-query validation message in dynamic input field but on submit only first input field is showing error message .below you can find the code and screenshot
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZVRl.png)

```
$("input").each(function () {$(this).rules("add",
            {

                required: true,

                messages: {
                    required: "enter item number",
                },

            });
    });
```

Comment: what is the id attribute of "item number" inputs ? same or different from each other ?

Comment: $("#submitbutton").click(function () {

        var ArrserviceCode = $("#ddlService option:selected").text().split('-');
        var serviceCode = ArrserviceCode[0];
        $('#hdServiceCode').val(serviceCode);
        
        $("#slt_participantdetail input").each(function (index) {
            $(this).rules("add",
                {

                    required: true,

                    messages: {
                        required: "enter item number"
                    }

                });
        });

Comment: please look at the screenshot

Comment: im getting error message for first input field but not all field

Comment: please send final html of the page if its possible

Comment: if u see my screenshot then u can give solution to that.......i have multiple input fields those are dynamically generated... for that i need to give validation.......on submit im getting only for first field ...for remaining field error message is not showing first time....

Comment: dynamically generated fields should have different id attributes